# Cname records for SAAS customers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, saas, cname

I'm working on a SAAS product. It's hosted on Windows Azure.

I need to give our customers to option to have CName records.

Our app URL looks like this: login.appname.com

When a customer is created they get their own address created for them that looks like this: login.appname.com/CustomerCompanyName

What I want to do is have our customers URL's look like : login.CustomerCompanyName.com/

What is the best way to go about this.
It's a webapp building in ASP.NET 4/ MVC4 hosted on Microsoft Azure.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Noel

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the technical limitation with your requirement.

1. Your application is running at login.appname.com
2. Customer is created and you provide specific site as login.appname.com/customercompanyname

Note: At this time customercompanyname.com is not even a registered domain or if it is registered it may belong to someone else. (or do you register the customercompanyname.com domain first and then create the new customer in Azure App?

What you want to do is very complex to achieve. It is not impossible however every time you will do that, you will have to modify your Azure app to handle the host header. I personally believe a very ugly work.

So if you want to know what is needed, here is just what I think (others may be different or better solution):

1. Register a domain name for your customer (customerAcompanyB.com)
2. Create a custom folder in your Windows Azure Application during development
3. Modify your your Azure application to handle customerAcompanyB.com  hostheader so you can route the request to appname.com/folder_name
4. In your customerAcompanyB.com domain registrar setup CNAME to route your appname.com